# rsync the most recent folder

Tags: shell, files, rsync, filenames

I have a backup software that creates folders every x amount of hours.
like this:

```
170425-1000/
170425-1100/
170425-1200/
```

(the name of the folder has the timestamp, and that is also given by the "last modified" property on the file system.

I want to rsync the most recent folder (including all its files and subfolders)

Comment: `rsync` to where?

Comment: Do you delete backups from the target before you delete them from the source? If not, why can't you just `rsync` everything and let it skip items that have already been copied successfully?

Comment: rsync to another server/folder etc, I dont think it matters.

Comment: I dont delete the backups from the target, the folder gets overwritten always, with the latest folder, thats why i want to rsync only the latest one, (the folder structure inside those folders in the example above is always the same)

Comment: So you have a fixed target directory that is to contain the contents of the most recent local backup? And is this target directory local or remote? This is important.

Comment: Next question. If the `rsync` crashes and burns (failed source disk, for example) half way through the copy process you'll end up with a partial target backup too. Are you comfortable knowing that your backup could be useless right at the time you need it most?

Comment: 1) The target is remote, Im connecting via ssh key, previously uploaded on target.
2) No problem with that, this is a daily offsite copy, from a local server with hourly backups, and the target is running ZFS, so it takes a daily snapshot also, so worst scenario, I will have the previous day on the remote server, or the day before, or the one before that one, etc., Also, the target replicates to another server, locally on the remote site, so it the target breaks, I have the replicated copy, and then I will continue resyncing there.

Comment: Sounds like you know what you want. Could you please update your question with this extra information so it's easy for new readers to see. We can then both delete our comments that are no longer required

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the most recent directory is the one whose name comes last in lexicographic order. So it's the last element in the expansion of `*` or any other pattern that matches the directory names.

```
sync_latest_dir () {
  eval "last=\${$#}"
  rsync -a "$last" remote-host:/some/where/
}
sync_latest_dir [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-*
```

Comment: Wouldn't running `rsync` on the parent directory with the `--ignore-existing` flag achieve the same thing?

Comment: @Mioriin Usually, yes, but according to the comments under the question this isn't desired here.